# how to sort an array in a nested array which is located under an object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I have a collection data like below.

```
{
    "name": "Devices",
    "exten": {
        "parameters": [{
                "name": "Date",
                "value": ["5","2"]
            }, {
                "name": "Time",
                "value": ["2"]
            }, {
                "name": "Season",
                "value": ["6"]
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

I want to take all data which is name "Devices" and sort by first index of "Value" which is parameter name is "Date"

ex: mongo will get

```
name = "devices"
exten.parameters.name = "Date"
```

will sort it by

```
exten.parameters.value[0]
```

in this example it will be sorted by "5".

below query returns 0 record.

```
db.brand.aggregate(
    { $match: {
        "name" : "Devices"
    }},
     { $unwind: "$exten.parameters" },
    { $match: {
        'exten.parameters.name': 'Date'
    }},
    { $sort: {
        'exten.parameters.value': -1
    }}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "name":"Devices"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$exten.parameters"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "exten.parameters.name":"Date"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "name":1,
            "exten":1,
            "firstParam":{
                $arrayElemAt:["$exten.parameters.value",0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            "firstParam":1
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "firstParam":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da02fb86472ba670fd8c159"),
    "name" : "Devices",
    "exten" : {
        "parameters" : [
            {
                "name" : "Date",
                "value" : [
                    "5",
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "Date",
                "value" : [
                    "2",
                    "7"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "Time",
                "value" : [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "Season",
                "value" : [
                    "6"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da02fb86472ba670fd8c159"),
    "name" : "Devices",
    "exten" : {
        "parameters" : {
            "name" : "Date",
            "value" : [
                "2",
                "7"
            ]
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da02fb86472ba670fd8c159"),
    "name" : "Devices",
    "exten" : {
        "parameters" : {
            "name" : "Date",
            "value" : [
                "5",
                "2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run it, mongo says "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",

Comment: @sakirow You seem to be running very old version of mongo.

Comment: mongo version is 3.2.10

Comment: ty for rply, I realized, every data, can have only 1 parameters which is name=date, your data has 2, first has 5, second has 2, actualy 2 must be belong to another device which is name=device, by the way the updated query returns errmsg" : "The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion",

Comment: your output is the exact data in my mongo db,I want to get it sorted by value.